# Either or generics in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface which accepts a generic

`export interface ConfigTable<T> {..}`

When I go to use it I want to have the Type be an either or

```
  private configMyRowTable: ConfigTable<MyRow> = {
  ...
  };

  private configGlobalTable: ConfigTable<GlobalRow> = {
   ....
  };

  public workTable : ConfigTable<MyRow | GlobalRow> = this.configMyRowTable;
```

but later when defining it I get

```
 this.workTable = this.configGlobalTable;
```

```
Type 'ConfigTable<GlobalRow>' is not assignable to type 'ConfigTable<MyRow| GlobalRow>'.
  Type 'MyRow| GlobalRow' is not assignable to type 'GlobalRow'.
    Type 'MyRow' is missing the following properties from type 'GlobalRow': prop1, prop2
    ts(2322)
```

is this possible with Typescript generics or am I misunderstanding how to use them?

here is link to playground
[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQiXQQHMAVTAIwBtgAecgPjgG8AoOOAC2EwBM0AZwBccSrWAAJPoKiMmAbQC6Abk5x+CIWBqYAngDEIEVFAD8YqibqYk6gL7t2oSLEQo0WXOOp0ZAmgKbBokwDT8lnAA1sD6EOji6lwwCDB0UUIwUMikyTwwALY0mdm5+bg0NPg0CNjRUQAU-JgwmGLkAJRwALwsAG4QCPz5QtBtklHWELb27E4u4OMeZt54EnQAShAA7gBCmEJ4HFzYMwCuhUgAolBQ0EKlOUikKo7OrsvIqzh4ALL6ADq0GiABltDBtjs4KBUEh+EJfJIoQcjiEuC1UABBfiCfhiLLPPIaQQCWpIYAEsovCrnLIQQpoAD6UGAojghPKGjOhUZKHZnJp8w+S3c3y8vzgAHEaBAqJgaMCoGCIVCYSA4QikVtdqjgAAaOAApUqrJqk5wQ5CMgU-jkCBUon5K024D8Qz3QqOrkLbB6ISIrHouDcogkUjGkHgrIbSkEMNkWP0SPK6OQ3YsHrBri8QJQdmKDRcLisOBhCJiADkmOAOLxlcNqXSccrABEseRrnAsa3W9dW5W4A59UXi6Xy-i4NXZOTgA24E26FW+z3QQBJABy10Hw9HJbLCHCk8r2DpMAZzNZQnni5b+AAqgBlcgAeT+102AHpNtdH3AAMQ7iOxZjgeR5VjyfIwNejZpEuU74G+74buQj5AaOyjAcWWg6HoRgmGYYhYDQRxYQ46ihsQZAynKCommmsZiIQVEUH4DA0fKipRqqGa9NmPCyMIYiFiB+4TlWNZ1m6N5wS27adt2vb9uholsGBFZTqS-CzjJzbLtcq6btuQ5YSB46HhplYuqQtoegyunwZWWKPo+a5SlurZwIYmxviponmeBU7Wba9oOS2zmue5-biC+flmepx6QcA-JhVWiF-MhqFxXAmGjjhugGMYphoERCqkRo5HOFwYDnLQdRwDs3ExmxTEJqxkjJkCTXptCAA+0qypx9E8TsmajjA3DaAAdGcLEpqaMCxhRIE1XV2ANd1sYAEytSxSbzWmar9RxdHdVCY0gRN02zeGJ1camEJLfMQA)

Comment: Shouldn't `ConfigTable<MyRow | GlobalRow>` be `ConfigTable<MyRow> | ConfigTable<GlobalRow>` if you want one or the other?

Comment: I face no issue here. Check example below:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQiXQQHMAVTAIwBtgAecgPjgG8AoOOAE0xkwBcccuwC+7djACeYPAFkpAJQgB3OAF42guEgCuAWyppRAbkky8AcRoQqmGsrWbWVIQGcYUZKQA0cMFAQYACMQnqGaH4BQQBMYQZGUKbs2DSYbm5wAIJsnP5eAG58eNhEJKQKjpS0wEKExGTVdPSVqizOeVy8-EKs2gCs4lzJeQEIRahwpQ2k1rb2TbUEZY3UzXN2Dm0auVxdfNouQgDkmMdRgSFC-RexQgBsQ3DJe2C6tAjYcCrQANaLcDqKwoawYrTUAB84Bt7I52nAYAALBBuAB003K4MWZk6YwmeEwAAoAJS7PYI5Fon5Qf6gnZIlHo4EwmjYzricRAA

Could you please provide playground link with repro?

Comment: OK tried to reimplement best I can, I am using this as part of a larger Angular app, so hoping I copied all relevant info into a TS playground above in edited post

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue - I did not provide enough in the original question but did in the TS playground. One of the objects in the generic was extending from the other and did not have all required fields

Comment: The error literally figured it out for you, I found the TS error very confusing in the beginning but they'll get clearer the more you see them. (trust me, you'll see enough of them haha)